# how does JVM able to calculate array length using ArrayName.length property?

Tags: java, c

From what I've learnt in Java is that Arrays are passed as reference..
That means pointers are used internally in java.

In C whenever we pass an array inside a function, it too is passed by reference and thats why we can't compute it's size using sizeof() operator. Like this,

1st case:->

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

int array[5];
printf("size of the array is: %lu\n", sizeof(array)/sizeof(int));

return 0;
}
```

and the output will be

```
size of the array is: 5
```

2nd case:->

```
#include<stdio.h>

void calculate_size(int *);
int main(int argc, char** argv) {

int array[5];
calculate_size(array);

return 0;
}

//Function definition...
void calculate_size(int p[]) {

printf("size of the array is: %lu\n", sizeof(p)/sizeof(int));

}
```

and the output is

```
size of the array is: 2
```

In the first case, it has given us exact length of the array, but in 2nd case the length is absurd and wrong.

It's because, the array is passed as reference inside the function and therefore the base address is passed here. That's why it is causing the sizeof() operator to consider, that above array has only single element in it and the size is therefore calculated on the basis of that consideration.

Now same thing goes with java. Here too, array is passed as reference.
Then how does "arrayname.length" property calculates it's length. Like this,

```
//Java code snippet...

int array[10];
System.out.println("Length of the array is "+array.length);
```

Even inside a function.
Can you elaborate that to me.

Comment: *"Can you elaborate that to me."* - They are two completely unrelated languages. End of story. If you are asking how the JVM handles it internally, that is a completely different story (and too broad for SO)

Comment: Also neither Java nor C pass arrays as references. In C it decays to a pointer which is passed by value, in Java arrays are reference types and you are passing a reference to the array by value.

Comment: arrays in Java are objects, like `std::array` or `std::vector` in C++, unlike POD arrays

Comment: You are comparing apples with pears. A C array is something *completely* different then one in Java.

Comment: Mr @alk I don't know that, can you tell me the source where I can read about that

Comment: @YatendraRathore: Please see  [*BeeOnRope*'s answer below.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45387134/694576)

Answer (score 2):

Java arrays are Objects, that embed (at least) the length field and the array elements. So a reference to an array is really a reference to that object, from which the length can be extracted.

C arrays, on the other hand, are essentially unadorned arrays and so there is no included length field. The use of `sizeof` to determine the length works only on arrays (and not decayed pointers) where the compiler can see the declaration including the length (with the exception of VLAs, which have special handling).

Answer (score 2):

In the second example you actually divide the pointer size by the size of an integer. So in your system the pointer size is twice longer than an integer.